# How to click a menu item present inside an iframe in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have a menu item named as Transform table after clicking on it more items are shown for selection. These are all present inside an iframe. I want to click on the options available inside Transform Table, but when I am searching for the options the main pop gets closed. Please suggest some way to keep it open and the select the options in it.

````
            const body = $iframe.contents().find('body');
            let getElement = cy.wrap(body);
            getElement.find(getdatasourcelocator.SearchBox).should('be.visible', { timeout: 30000 }).type(datasourceType);
            getElement = cy.wrap(body);
            getElement.find('.textCsv').click();
            getElement = cy.wrap(body);
               getElement.find(getdatasourcelocator.URL).type(entityURL);
               getElement = cy.wrap(body);
               getElement.find('button').contains('Next').click();
               getElement = cy.wrap(body);
               getElement.wait(15000);
               getElement.find('button').contains('Transform table').click().then(()=>{
                cy.get('button[data-automation-id="PromoteHeaders"]').should('be.visible');
                cy.contains('li','Use first row as headers').should('be.visible', { timeout: 30000 }).click()
               });
            });
        }```
````

Comment: I am able to click the "Transform Table' button present inside the iframe using this "getElement.find('button').contains('Transform table').click()" it open a pane and closes it immediately and then search for "Use first row as headers" outside the pane. Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot target elements or interact with anything in an iframe - regardless of it being the same domain or cross-domain iframe. Here is a known [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136).

As workaround, you can try to use something from the comments:

1. Add custom command.

   ```
   Cypress.Commands.add('iframe', { prevSubject: 'element' }, $iframe => {
     return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
       $iframe.on('load', () => {
         resolve($iframe.contents().find('body'));
       });
     });
   });
   ```
2. And use this command.

   ```
   // for <iframe id="foo" src="bar.html"></iframe>
   cy.get('#foo').iframe().find('.bar').should('contain', 'Success!');
   ```